# Do i need a clutch replacement for my 2003 vw jetta?

Tags: clutch, jetta

I am not very good at describing car problems, but i'll try my best.

My 2003 Jetta is an automatic. Here recently, while I drive, the engine light comes on. My car revs very high, even though i am not going fast and/or "flooring" the gas pedal. It never falls below 2nd gear anymore. Also, my engine starts to get warm, just judging by the temp gauge.

Do i need to have my clutch replaced, or is it something else?

I hope that wasn't too confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You could very well need the "clutches" in your transmission replaced, but automatic transmissions do not have a "clutch" per se. They utilize a torque convertor to get power from the engine to the transmission. What this sounds like is your transmission is slipping due to bad internal clutches or even a lack of or burnt transmission fluid. This definitely sounds like something you need to take to the tranny shop for diagnosis.